# why fusedLocationClient lastLocation function never getting called

Tags: android

i'm trying get current location latitude and longitude So i tried something like below.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                Log.d("log","location  is $location")
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    Log.d("log","location  is $location")
                }
            }
    }
```

but i never get the logs

I have added these things in my manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and also implemented these in build.gradle

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

Please answer in a very easy way as my question is very simple and straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 100% sure, this is a permission issue. And you didn't included failed listener you are not getting what was the issue.

add this where ever you want

```
fun checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) { //Can add more as per requirement
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ),
                123
            )
        }
    }
```

Then in onCreate method call this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkPermission();
        }
```

Then don't request location on onCreate method. as it is not still ready you will not get location.

request it on some other function.

Comment: This was working. but why it is needed run time permission only